# timer_create and timerid, is this allowed?

Tags: c++, posix

I can't set the `evp` parameter to `NULL`, but I'd like to receive the `timerid` in my timer handler, just as if it had been set to `NULL`. I was thinking about calling:

```
struct sigevent se;
se.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
se.sigev_notify_attributes = {};
se.sigev_notify_function = timer_handler;

timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &se, &se.sigev_value);
```

I am not certain, whether I should do this, even if it worked. Is there another way to obtain the `timerid` in the timer handler, without setting `evp` to `NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

That is definitely invalid because `timer_t` could be longer than an `int`. Also passing a pointer to a union is not the same as passing a pointer to one of its members.

You need to do something like this:

```
timer_t timerid;
struct sigevent se = { 0 };
se.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
se.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timerid;
se.sigev_notify_function = timer_handler;

if (timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &se, &timerid) < 0)
    abort(); // or whatever

// later...
if (timer_delete(timerid) < 0)
    abort();
```

In other words, you need to allocate space to hold the `timerid`, squirrel away a pointer to it in your `sigevent` structure, and remember to delete the timer when you are done with it.

Also you should always check system calls for errors and do something other than proceeding like nothing happened.

Comment: I think you should make `timerid` static in your example, otherwise `sival_ptr` will dangle.